# Strange Ruby Syntax?

Tags: ruby, string, hash

I'm doing the Ruby 20 minute tutorial on ruby-lang.org and I came across this code messing with the irb:

```
irb(main):015:0> def h(name)
irb(main):016:1> puts "Hello #{name}!"
irb(main):017:1> end
```

based on the explanation, the `#{name}` part is just adding the variable to the string? I thought this was an odd and verbose way of writing it so I just thought I'd try `"Hello" + name` and it worked exactly the same way..

I googled around trying to find a meaning to `#{}` and I cant find anything talking about it so I thought I'd ask the community.. what is the difference? Is there one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://symbolhound.com/?q=%23%7B%7D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes using `+` is easier, but in this case you left off the exclamation point.  Consider:

```
puts "Hello #{name}!"
```

vs.

```
puts "Hello " + name + "!"
```

I find the first more readable, especially when used several times in a string.

Also consider how easy it was to leave out the space after "Hello" in the second version:

```
puts "Hello" + name + "!"
```

is easy to write, but probably isn't what you mean.

Last, it makes an even bigger difference when what you're interpolating isn't a string:

```
puts "The Winner was #{name} with a score of #{score}!"
```

By the way, searching for "string interpolation" will probably make it easier to find things than just searching for the syntax.

Comment: Paul was riding shotgun for us on this one! ;)

Comment: @Maximus9000 When what you're interpolating is just a string, then yes, I'd say it's only a matter of syntactical preference, but it works for all kinds of Ruby values, which makes it more than just preference.  I updated my answer with an example of this.

Comment: String interpolation is often faster too. I can't imagine too many cases where the speed really matters, but just another reason to avoid ugly string addition.

Answer (score 4):

```
"Hello #{name}!"
"Hello " + name + "!"
```

[String interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) is almost always *much* easier to read, particularly if there's multiple values to interp.

It *may* become difficult if the value being interpolated is verbose:

```
"Attendees: #{names.collect(&:first_name).join(', ')}"
```

In cases like that, you might want to concatenate, or just use a temp variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that it's not just readability. Using string interpolation will do the right thing e.g. call `to_s` on the whatever is between `#{}`

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > "as" + 23
    TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String
    from (irb):1:in `+'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

As opposed to

```
1.9.3p194 :002 > "as #{23}"
 => "as 23"
```

Answer (score 2):

The biggest differences are ease of reading, conformance to idiomatic usage, and speed.

When using `"Hello " + name + "!"` you (well, the Ruby interpreter) creates a total of 3 additional strings, as opposed to `"Hello #{name}!"` where it only creates one additional string.

Keep in mind that using string interpolation (`"#{}"`) automatically calls `#to_s`, which may or may not be desired.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076579/string-concatenation-vs-interpolation-in-ruby) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The #{} is used for [string interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation), which allows you to easily and clearly put data in your strings. Ruby evaluates the content within the curly braces and then calls its `to_s` method, which every Ruby object inherits from Object.

This allows you to even do calculations within your strings, e.g.

```
"5 + 7 = #{5 + 7}"
=> "5 + 7 = 12"
```