# Fixnum String conversion

Tags: ruby

I want to get a string of the current time in Ruby:

```
"Time is " + Time.new.month + "/" + Time.new.day + "/" + Time.new.year
```

But it says "can't convert Fixnum into String". How can I fix this?

Comment: Off topic, but calling `Time.new` three times just to get a string is a potential bug every midnight of the last day of the month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you could just use right tool for the job: time formatting.

```
Time.new.strftime "Time is %m/%d/%Y" # => "Time is 11/13/2012"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `to_s`

```
"Time is " + Time.new.month.to_s + "/" + Time.new.day.to_s + "/" + Time.new.year.to_s
```

But event better is to use `strftime`

```
Time.new.strftime("Time is %-m/%e/%Y")
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby can only add string to string, so conversion is required. As a note, elements interpolated in double-quoted strings are automatically converted:

```
now = Time.new
"Time is #{now.month}/#{now.day}/#{now.year}"
```

It's also possible to combine them from an array where they are also automatically converted:

```
now = Time.new
"Time is " + [ now.month, now.day, now.year ].join('/')
```

You can also use `sprintf`-style interpolation:

```
now = Time.new
"Time is %d/%d/%d" % [ now.month, now.day, now.year ]
```

The second one gives you more control over formatting. For example `%02d` will pad with `0` to two places.

As Sergio points out, there's a special-purpose function for this formatting that is probably a better idea. Also `Time.now` is the traditional method for *now*, whereas `Time.new` is for creating arbitrary times.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, prefer string interpolation over concatenation. As you can clearly see in that ([thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076579/string-concatenation-vs-interpolation-in-ruby)), using string interpolation would have automatically called `to_s` for you.

Using string interpolation :

"Time is #{Time.new.month}/#{Time.new.day}/#{Time.new.year}"