# What does #{...} mean?

Tags: ruby

Such as in the following code from Why's Poignant Guide:

```
def wipe_mutterings_from( sentence ) 
     unless sentence.respond_to? :include?
         raise ArgumentError, "cannot wipe mutterings from a #{ sentence.class }"
     end
     while sentence.include? '('
         open = sentence.index( '(' )
         close = sentence.index( ')', open )
         sentence[open..close] = '' if close
     end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a Ruby double-quoted string—which includes string literals like `s = "…"` and `s = %Q{ ... }` and `s = <<ENDCODE`—the syntax `#{ … }` is used for "string interpolation", inserting dynamic content into the string. For example:

```
i = 42
s = "I have #{ i } cats!"
#=> "I have 42 cats!"
```

It is equivalent to (but more convenient **and** efficient than) using string concatenation along with explicit calls to `to_s`:

```
i = 42
s= "I have " + i.to_s + " cats!"
#=> "I have 42 cats!"
```

You can place arbitrary code inside the region, including multiple expressions on multiple lines. The final result of evaluating the code has `to_s` called on it to ensure that it is a string value:

```
"I've seen #{
  i = 10
  5.times{ i+=1 }
  i*2
} weasels in my life"
#=> "I've seen 30 weasels in my life"

[4,3,2,1,"no"].each do |legs|
  puts "The frog has #{legs} leg#{:s if legs!=1}"
end
#=> The frog has 4 legs
#=> The frog has 3 legs
#=> The frog has 2 legs
#=> The frog has 1 leg
#=> The frog has no legs
```

---

Note that this has no effect inside single-quoted strings:

```
s = "The answer is #{6*7}" #=> "The answer is 42"
s = 'The answer is #{6*7}' #=> "The answer is #{6*7}"

s = %Q[The answer is #{ 6*7 }] #=> "The answer is 42"
s = %q[The answer is #{ 6*7 }] #=> "The answer is #{6*7}"

s = <<ENDSTRING
The answer is #{6*7}
ENDSTRING
#=> "The answer is 42\n"

s = <<'ENDSTRING'
The answer is #{6*7}
ENDSTRING
#=> "The answer is #{6*7}\n"
```

---

For convenience, the `{}` characters for string interpolation are optional if you want to insert just the value of an instance variable (`@foo`), global variable (`$foo`), or class variable (`@@foo`):

```
@cats = 17
s1 = "There are #{@cats} cats" #=> "There are 17 cats"
s2 = "There are #@cats cats"   #=> "There are 17 cats"
```

Comment: You may want to add that spacing within brackets is irrelevant. `"I have #{i} cats"` is valid too.

Comment: @NielsB. Would you agree that the edit makes this clear, given that you can have multiple lines, and that there are examples showing no space?

Comment: Yeah, it's quite thorough now.

Answer (score 4):

`"#{}"` means in Ruby string interpolation.See [`Here`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+%22interpolation%22) for too many answers.

Comment: and string interpolation means that the content of the variable/expression is placed into the embedding string at that location.

Answer (score 1):

`#{}` is used for Ruby interpolation.  In this example,

this will raise an ArgumentError with the message,

`cannot wipe mutterings from a <whatever sentence.class evaluates to>`

This is a useful read - [String concatenation vs. interpolation in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076579/string-concatenation-vs-interpolation-in-ruby)