# Does #{}-style substitution work in ERB expressions?

Tags: ruby, erb

I'm adding a confirmation dialog to a delete operation in my rails tutorial, and I want to include some text from the object to be deleted. So I tried this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(article), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Really delete blog "#{article.title}"?' } %>
```

The substitution does not happen: the resulting dialog says `Really delete blog "#{article.title}"?`.

I've changed it to use format strings and it's working fine:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(article), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Really delete blog "%s"?' % article.title } %>
```

The substitution happens: the resulting dialog says `Really delete blog "Of cabbages and kings"?`

What do I change to make the more-readable "#{article.title}" work for me? What's the difference?

Comment: The other question (vote to close as duplicate) is easier to find on google and has a very helpful answer.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate, but I do believe that this discussion could be helpful to future ruby-ists. The question relates to the specific issue of double quotes vs. single quotes with the `#{}` interpolation (the other one only mentions the difference in passing). Perhaps the question / answers should be edited to make them more focused on this specific issue (subject could be: "why doesn't the `#{}` work" or similar).

Comment: Closing doesn't mean deleting. It just means no more answers are needed here. I think your answer covers everything needed on this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the `#{}` didn't work is the difference between double quotes `"` and single quotes `'`

**EDIT**: For a more complete description of string interpolation and using the `#{}` style, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089993/what-does-mean). to see why double-quotes vs. single quotes don't normally pose a meaningful performance issue, [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836467/is-there-a-performance-gain-in-using-single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-ruby). - credit to @PaulHicks for this edit.

Text in single quotes isn't pre-processed (parsed before creating the String object) while text in double quotes is pre-processed. So that:

```
'hello\n "world"!' == "hello\\n \"world\"!" #=> true
```

The following change would have worked fine (notice double quotes instead of single quotes):

```
<%= link_to ... confirm: "Really delete blog \"#{article.title}\"?" } %>
```

**EDIT**: As @Stefan suggested, you could also use the `%Q()` notation to avoid escaping:

```
confirm: %Q(Really delete blog "#{article.title}"?)
```

(You can see more options in the link above, regarding interpolation)

Good luck!

Comment: Aha. I've obviously been away from Ruby for too long, I forgot that. I've been looking for a canonical question that this one duplicates; so far I've found half-a-dozen 0-upvote and 1-upvote equivalents, but nothing that stands out.. seems like there should be a canonical question for this..

Comment: You can also use the `%Q(...)` literal to avoid escaping: `confirm: %Q(Really delete blog "#{article.title}"?)`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, @PaulHicks . I wasn't aware of the distinction. And thanks @ for providing a cleaner option. I'll edit the answer with the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way, look at `" "` and `' '`

```
"Really delete blog '#{article.title}'?"
```