# For rails app, how to make flash[:notice] to show a complex sentence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, notice

I want to do something like this:

in controller:

```
res=1+3
if ...
flash[:notice]="the result is" + res
end
```

However, I found that it does not work, and the error message is like this:

```
no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
```

Comment: I am not sure if the question is downvote, since at least 7 of my classmates think this is extremely useful and believe the question is very clear. But is OK, finally I got the right answer in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert it to the `res` variable which is an integer to a string:

```
flash[:notice]="the result is" + res.to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using string **interpolation**:

```
flash[:notice] = "the result is #{res}"
```

Which is better than **concatenation** (using `+` ) because:

1. Its faster
2. As you can see it automatically do `.to_s` for you
3. Less typing (developers are lazy ofcourse)

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076579/string-concatenation-vs-interpolation-in-ruby) for more details and comparison