# .map on array into string

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dictionary

I have a an array returned when using `.map`:

```
<li class="mix <%= p.sectors.map {|s| "#{s.name}"} %> all">
```

gives array:

```
["Content Management System", "Web Design", "Web Development"]
```

at the moment the returned result in my view is:

```
<li class="mix ["Content Management System", "Web Design", "Web Development"] all mix_all" </li>
```

I want to use each s.name as a class name, but I have an issue when using:

```
<li class="mix <%= p.sectors.map {|s| "#{s.name}"}.join(" ") %> all">
```

where each word is being treated as a separate class, so Web Design is now two classes rather than one.

Is there a way to have Web Design as one class or do I need to use different naming conventions, like Web-Design to make this work?

Comment: BTW, why do you use such dreadful construction as `"#{s.name}"`?

Comment: "Web Design" are two classes because [class names are separated by white space](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

Comment: @MarekLipka in reference to the construction..what would you do differently?

Comment: i started with that, but read that interpolation was more efficient?

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076579/string-concatenation-vs-interpolation-in-ruby  or am i misinterpreting this?

Comment: @Richlewis you're misinterpreting this. It was about string concatenation vs interpolation. You have no concatenation here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
mix <%= p.sectors.map { |s| s.name.gsub(/\s+/, '-') }.join(' ') %>
```

Comment: Thanks, works a treat :-), ill accept once default time constraints pass

Comment: Can you show the final output ? I am not getting it

Comment: @ArupRakshit `["Content Management System", "Web Design", "Web Development"].map { |s| s.gsub(/\s/, '-') }` `# => ["Content-Management-System", "Web-Design", "Web-Development"]`

Comment: Good answer, but I would put it in a helper method.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a class name with spaces in it.  So, you need to convert your phrases into class names.  Class names are typically downcased (though this isn't a requirement) and separated with hyphens (rather than underscores, although again this isn't a requirement, just a convention).

So, you could downcase and hyphen-separate them as follows

```
<li class="mix <%= p.sectors.map{|sector| sector.name.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z0-9\-]+/, '-') }.join(' ') %> all">
```

My regex here will replace 1 or more instances of anything that's not a letter, number or hyphen, with a hyphen, so the result should be

```
<li class="mix content-management-system web-design web-development all mix_all">
```

You could move this into the model:

```
#in Sector class
def html_classname
  self.name.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z0-9\-]+/, '-')
end
```

and then change the view code to

```
<li class="mix <%= p.sectors.map(&:html_classname).join(' ') %> all">
```