# how to change order notification from Dear Customer to Dear @username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Please how do I change the order and shipment mailer notification to show the users Name in the salutation instead of 'Dear Customer'

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use string interpolation in this case:

`<%= "Dear #{@username}" %>`

[String concatenation vs. interpolation in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076579/string-concatenation-vs-interpolation-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
<%= "Dear " + @username %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I'll try this out when I get to my computer and mark as Answer. Thanks..

Comment: Hi, so I've added this to my mailer view but it still shows Dear Customer. Is there something else I should do for the change to effect?

Comment: <%= Spree.t('shipment_mailer.shipped_email.dear_customer') %>   -- That is the part with the salutation. i've replaced with <%='Dear ' + @user.first_name %> but Its still shows "Dear Customer"

Comment: `unterminated string meets end of file` -- i'm getting this error