# Irrespective of benchmarks, what is the preferred convention (style + syntax) for methods that generate strings in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, syntax, coding-style, convention

For example, to get the full name of a User model with first_name and last_name attributes, one could write:

```
def full_name
  self.name_first + " " + self.name_last
end
```

**or**

```
def full_name
  "#{self.name_first} #{self.name_last}"
end
```

I've noticed that I personally prefer the latter. It may be subjective, but which is generally preferred? What are the advantages/ disadvantages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10076632/2697183

Comment: possible duplicate of [String concatenation vs. interpolation in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076579/string-concatenation-vs-interpolation-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

According to the community Ruby coding style guide (https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#string-interpolation):

> Prefer string interpolation and string formatting instead of string concatenation

Also, regarding `self` (https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-self-unless-required):

> Avoid self where not required. (It is only required when calling a self write accessor.)

So, finally this method could be something like:

```
def full_name
  "#{name_first} #{name_last}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The first version – concatenating with `+` – will raise an error if either attribute is `nil` or is not of type `String`.

The second version – using expression substitution – calls `to_s` on everything substituted, so `nil` becomes `""` and therefore wouldn't raise an error. This also applies to other classes such as `Array`, `Hash`, etc. that implement `to_s`.