# Ruby question: syntax error whilst using gets

Tags: ruby, string, gets

I am attempting to run the following program, which will give out a simple greeting taking user input. However, whenever I run the code I get the following message:

**syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting do or '{' or '('**

I've tried replacing the single quote marks with doubles, and I've also tried placing '()' around the variable names.

```
puts 'First name:  '
first_name = gets.chomp
puts 'Middle name:  '
middle_name = gets.chomp
puts 'Surname:  '
surname = gets.chomp

puts "Greets to you," + first_name + middle_name + surname "! Welcome to Valhalla!"
```

Answer (score 1):

@eux already gave a correct answer to the syntax error in your example.

I just want to show another way to generate the expected output. It's a common Ruby idiom to use string interpolation instead of string concatenation. With string interpolation, you can generate your output like this

```
puts "Greets to you, #{first_name} #{middle_name} #{surname}! Welcome to Valhalla!"
```

String interpolation has many advantages – as described in this [answer and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076579/string-concatenation-vs-interpolation-in-ruby). In the context of your question the pros are:

- It is shorter
- It is much clearer where to put whitespace
- And It is overall easier to read and understand

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `+` before `! Welcome to Valhalla!` at the last line:

```rb
puts "Greets to you," + first_name + middle_name + surname + "! Welcome to Valhalla!"
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot. Works fine now. I'll just need to add some spacing (realised that with new input). Thank you!