# Call a function within Quotes " "

Tags: ruby, string, function

I am a beginner in Ruby. Could someone help me with this?
I want to call a method within ""

```
def callme
"this string"  # this is usually a path that I want to source from a single location 
end               


v= "string + callme "
```

how do I call the function within quotes here? The quotes are essential for my code.

Comment: When you say *"The quotes are essential for my code"* can you explain? Is the intended result `"string + this string"` or `"string this string"` or `"string + \"this string\""`, etc. as of right now it is very unclear. BTW as a minor grammatical suggestion there are no *functions* in ruby, only *methods*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string interpolation / concatenation:

```rb
def hi
  'Hello'
end

def world
  'World'
end

# Concatenation
hi + ' ' + world   #=> "Hello World"

# Interpolation
"#{hi} #{world}"   #=> "Hello World"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076579/string-concatenation-vs-interpolation-in-ruby) for more details

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is *string interpolation*. The syntax for this is `#{...}`, like so:

```
v= "string + #{callme} "
```

This sets the variable `v` to `"string + this string "`.

[Reference](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings)